# Visual Studio Community 2015 slow debugging

Tags: debugging, build, visual-studio-2015

I have recently bought new laptop:Hp specter x360 i7-6500 with 8gb RAM.
I have installed Visual Studios 2015 Community in an offline mode, later I updated it.I am currently working in c# window forms.
The point is when I press the button 'Start Debugging', VS build the program in normal speed, but it takes like 10-15 sec to show the output, even for the small programs. This whole thing is for first time debugging after code editing, if I close it and run it again without changing the code, it shows the output on the spot.

And if I run the same program in my old laptop, which has lower specs and same VS, that laptop show the result much quicker.

[image: While Debugging]
[image: After the output]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, I see that VS tries to download PDB symbols for system assemblies, which are used by your application. Loading the debug symbols provides simplify debugging of an application but it also slows down the application loading. 
You can change symbols loading settings, in the *Tools-Options-Debugging-Symbols* menu of Visual Studio. Here you can disable symbol loading (if you would use this option you need to load symbols manually using the *Debugging-Windows-Modules* interface). Or exclude system modules which usually are not necessary to debug a common application. 
Check [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/) which provides a great description about how VS uses debug symbols.